# ifelse returning only numeric value

Tags: r

I am a new R user and have just started working with dataframes.
I am trying to create a new column within a dataframe (using the code below). The problem is the new column created contains numeric values, yet all the columns used in the code are non-numeric

I have tried looking for answer on-line but cannot find an answer

```
dataframe$newcol <- ifelse(dataframe$colA == "London", dataframe$colA, dataframe$colB)'
```

Comment: It is a case of `factor` columns.  I guess your 'colA', 'colB' are `factor` type.  Convert them to `character` and it should work

Comment: i.e. try `dataframe$newcol <- ifelse(dataframe$colA == "London", as.character(dataframe$colA), as.character(dataframe$colB))`

Answer (score 2):

R defaults alot of character columns to factors, which can be a little tricky.

You can look at the class of variables like this

```
sapply( dataframe, class )
```

or

```
str( dataframe )
```

You can convert multiple columns like this:

```
dataframe[ , c("colA" ,"colB") ] <- sapply( dataframe[ , c("colA" ,"colB") ] , as.character )
```

you can convert one column at a time like this

```
dataframe$colA <- as.character( dataframe$colA )
```

if you are converting numeric cols do it like this

```
dataframe$colX <- as.numeric( as.character( dataframe$colX ))
```

Your code should work now - note that I changed == to %in%

```
dataframe$newcol <- ifelse(dataframe$colA %in% "London", dataframe$colA, dataframe$colB)
```

you can save yourself typing by using transform here

```
dataframe <- transform( dataframe , newcol = ifelse( colA %in% "London", colA, colB))
```

Answer (score 0):

You could write a small new `ifelse.fac` function for this purpose.

```
ifelse.fac <- Vectorize(function(x, y, z) if (x) y else z)
```

Applying on data yields:

```
dat$newcol <- ifelse.fac(dat$colA == "London", dat$colA, dat$colB)
dat
#         colA          colB    newcol
# 1     London not in France    London
# 2     London not in France    London
# 3     London not in France    London
# 4     London not in France    London
# 5      Paris     in France in France
# 6  Marseille     in France in France
# 7      Paris     in France in France
# 8      Paris     in France in France
# 9     London not in France    London
# 10 Marseille     in France in France
```

And the factor structure remains intact:

```
str(dat)
# 'data.frame': 10 obs. of  3 variables:
# $ colA  : Factor w/ 3 levels "London","Marseille",..: 1 1 1 1 3 2 3 3 1 2
# $ colB  : Factor w/ 2 levels "in France","not in France": 2 2 2 2 1 1 1 1 2 1
# $ newcol: Factor w/ 5 levels "London","Marseille",..: 1 1 1 1 4 4 4 4 1 4
```

---

***Data***

```
dat <- structure(list(colA = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 
3L, 1L, 2L), .Label = c("London", "Marseille", "Paris"), class = "factor"), 
    colB = structure(c(2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L
    ), .Label = c("in France", "not in France"), class = "factor")), row.names = c(NA, 
-10L), class = "data.frame")

head(dat)
#        colA          colB
# 1    London not in France
# 2    London not in France
# 3    London not in France
# 4    London not in France
# 5     Paris     in France
# 6 Marseille     in France
```